# Loop reading dat file incorrectly

Tags: c++

Goodday,

I have a loop reading a dat file but the loop reads the data incorrectly. My dat file contains the following data

```
46780976 3750.40
W 250.00
D 1200.00
W 75.00
W 375.00
D 1200.00
I 5.50
W 400.00
W 600.00
D 450.50
W 35.65
```

The output should be

```
Account number: 46780976
Opening balance: R3750.40

Transaction    Amount    Balance Bank costs
Withdrawal     250.00    4000.00
Deposit       1200.00Ct  2800.00
Withdrawal        75.00  2725.00
Withdrawal      1375.00   1350.00
Deposit        1200.00Ct 1550.00
Interest         5.50    1555.50
Withdrawal      400.00   1155.50
Withdrawal      600.00   555.50     25.00
Deposit         450.00Ct 1005.50
Withdrawal       35.65    969.85
Banking costs    25.00    969.60

Closing balance: R969.60
```

I get the following

```
Account number : 46780976

Opening Balance : R 3750.4

Transaction        Amount          Balance         Bank Costs


Withdrawal            250            3500.4
Deposit            0 Ct            3500.4
Interest              0            3500.4

Withdrawal            250            3225.4
Deposit            1200 Ct            4425.4
Interest              0            4425.4

Withdrawal            75            4325.4
Deposit            1200 Ct            5525.4
Interest              0            5525.4

Withdrawal            375            5125.4
Deposit            1200 Ct            6325.4
Interest              0            6325.4

Withdrawal            375            5925.4
Deposit            1200 Ct            7125.4
Interest              0            7125.4

Withdrawal            375            6725.4
Deposit            1200 Ct            7925.4
Interest              5.5            7930.9

Withdrawal            400            7505.9
Deposit            1200 Ct            8705.9
Interest              5.5            8711.4

Withdrawal            600            8086.4
Deposit            1200 Ct            9286.4
Interest              5.5            9291.9

Withdrawal            600            8666.9
Deposit            450.5 Ct            9117.4
Interest              5.5            9122.9

Withdrawal            35.65            9062.25
Deposit            450.5 Ct            9512.75
Interest              5.5            9518.25

Withdrawal            35.65            9457.6
Deposit            450.5 Ct            9908.1
Interest              5.5            9913.6
Bank Costs           25            9888.6            25


Closing Balance : R 9888.6
Press any key to continue . . .
```

My code :

```
do { 
   in_stream >> letter;

if (letter == 'W')

    in_stream >> withdrawal;
    openBalance -= withdrawal;
    cout << "\nWithdrawal" << "            "<< withdrawal << "            " << openBalance << endl;
    out_stream << withdrawal;

if (letter == 'D')

    in_stream >> deposit;
    openBalance += deposit;
    cout << "Deposit" <<"            "<< deposit <<" Ct" <<"            " << openBalance << endl;
    out_stream << deposit;


if (letter == 'I')

    in_stream >> interest;
    openBalance += interest;
    cout << "Interest" <<"              "<< interest <<"            " << openBalance << endl;
    out_stream << interest;

 if (openBalance < 1000)
     cout << "Bank Costs" <<"           "<< bankCost <<"            " << openBalance <<"            " << bankCost << endl;
    openBalance -= bankCost;
    out_stream << bankCost;

} while(!in_stream.eof());
```

Please point me in the right direction

thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your bug, but will make your code more readable: [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem si with your if blocks.  In C++, the 'if' statement affects the immeidately following thing - line of code or block.so...

```
if( Xxx )
    thisHappensOnlyIfXxxIsTrue
thisAlwaysHappens

if( Xxx )
    thisHappensOnlyIfXxxIsTrue
    thisAlwaysHappens  // even though it's indented


if( Xxx ) {
    thisHappensOnlyIfXxxIsTrue
    thisDependsOnXxxToo
}
thisAlwaysHappens
```

The next problem is that you're not clearing your variables every time the loop restarts.  You need to insert a

```
do {
   deposit = 0;
   interest = 0;
   withdrawal = 0;
```

at the beginning (or end) of your loop, to ensure that you're not re-using the value from teh last loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the clearing part that worked. But I am still not getting the required out put. Same output with each letter repeated over and over. Please can you assist me with the output part.

Comment: You probably need to clear letter, every time through - even if it's not the cause, it's good practice.  You should also edit your original post to indicate the way the code looks now - it's very hard to psychically read your code and provide comments :)

Comment: I am still have a problem with the output.I cannot get it to output as per above. I have add the lines above from atk.

Comment: @user1291092: I don't see updated code in the question.  Have you edited your question to add it?

Comment: Glad to be of use :)  Would you kindly add the solution somewhere appropriate, so that other people who browse to this page will be able to learn from your work?

Answer (score 1):

As the first line is:

```
46780976 3750.40
```

This line will pass but without what was intended:

```
in_stream >> letter;
```

Assuming of course that `letter` is of type `char`

**EDIT**

```
// You need to read in the initial values here

do { 
   in_stream >> letter;

if (letter == 'W')
{
    in_stream >> withdrawal;
    openBalance -= withdrawal;
    cout << "\nWithdrawal" << "            "<< withdrawal << "            " << openBalance << endl;
    out_stream << withdrawal;
}

if (letter == 'D')
{
    in_stream >> deposit;
    openBalance += deposit;
    cout << "Deposit" <<"            "<< deposit <<" Ct" <<"            " << openBalance << endl;
    out_stream << deposit;
}

if (letter == 'I')
{

    in_stream >> interest;
    openBalance += interest;
    cout << "Interest" <<"              "<< interest <<"            " << openBalance << endl;
    out_stream << interest;
 }

 if (openBalance < 1000)
 {
     cout << "Bank Costs" <<"           "<< bankCost <<"            " << openBalance <<"            " << bankCost << endl;
    openBalance -= bankCost;
    out_stream << bankCost;
  }

} while(!in_stream.eof());
```